# Markdown syntax color theme

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown

I am giving advice to different research groups at our university. Open Research is promoted highly and many groups use R for statistical analysis. Many are also interested in using Markdown, Pandoc and Zotero to compile manuscripts and cooperate with other research groups. The researchers are from different disciplines, but have limited time for programming or tweaking long codes.

I have for some time used Sublime Text and I am very happy with this editor. However, I have also begun to look into using Neovim and promote it as a true Open Research. It also have a very nice package to interact with Zotero, and the Goyo plugin is very nice. BUT working in Sublime Text I find the color theme for Markdown (GFM) to be very good, and speed up much of the editing work. I have not been able to find any color theme or plug that will do the same. I am thinking especially of citations (in brackets), url:s, code to include imaging etc

Sorry if I have missed something obvious.

Comment: GFM is a flavor of markdown, not a colorscheme. I think that [vim-markdown](https://github.com/gabrielelana/vim-markdown) is the plugin which works best for this markdown flavor (but I didn't test a lot of plugin). However if I may point out something: Trying to switch a research team to a modal editor like vim or neovim when they are used to a classical text editor and didn't ask for a change sounds like asking for trouble, (neo)vim has a steep learning curve to get productive and you'll have to make sure that people are interesting in changing :)

Comment: If you just want colors: https://github.com/cormacrelf/vim-colors-github. Agreed with statox, though. Welcome to [vi.se]! You might be interested in the [tour]. By *Open Research* do you perhaps mean "open source"? I think it would be helpful if you [edit] your question down to the core, which seems to be "how can I make markdown syntax highlighting look similar to GitHub's colors?"